# how to find the limits for this type of integrals using spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, jacobian

> move the integral
>
> $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{8}$
>
> to spherical coordinates integral.

i dont know how to find the limits of the integral when moving to $\theta, \ r , \phi $

can you please guide me with finding the limits because i always get a mistakes there

> my trial :

reading the $\mathrm dz$ we see that $ 0 \leq z^2 \leq 1-x^2-y^2 $
or $ 0\leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1 $

reading $\mathrm dy$ we see that $ 0 \leq y^2 \leq \sqrt{1-x^2} $ or $ 0\leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

reading $dx$ we see that $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$

so the spherical limits :

$ 0\leq r^2 \leq 1$

$ 0 \leq r^2\sin(\theta)^2 \leq 1$

$ 0 \leq r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) \leq 1$

> how do i continue from here ? i think i made a mistake with $\phi$ because i didn't get the proper value for the integral after calculating in the spherical co-ordinates.

Comment: You lost the point that $x,y,z$ are all positive

Answer (score 0):

It follows from your computations that your integral is equal to$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}r^3\sin(\phi)\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm dr.$$But\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}r^3\sin(\phi)\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm dr&=\left(\int_0^1r^3\,\mathrm dr\right)\left(\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin(\phi)\,\mathrm d\phi\right)\left(\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\,\mathrm d\theta\right)\\&=\frac14\times1\times\frac\pi2\\&=\frac\pi8.\end{align}

Comment: how did you know that $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $

Comment: Because $x,y,z\leqslant0$.

Comment: also why is $ 0\leq r \leq 1 $ and not $ 0\leq r \leq \frac{1}{sin{\theta} }$

Comment: Why should we have that? The region that you are interested in is the part of the unit sphere in which all Cartesian coordinates are non-negative. So, $r$ can take any value from $0$ to $1$, whatever $\theta$ may be.

Comment: yes but the inequality says (by moving from xyz , to spherical ) that $ 0 \leq r^2sin(\theta)^2 \leq 1 $ so dividing makes the ineuality $(a)$ $ 0\leq r \leq \frac{1}{sin(\theta)} $ doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes. And you also have $0\leqslant x\leqslant1$, which means that $0\leqslant r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\leqslant1$, but you don't. impose that $r\leqslant\frac1{\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)}$, do you?